# Avoid duplicate code in SortedDictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-duplication

So I have two if stament to handle dictionary value.If the method is POST I just need to add the `status` params to the dictionary.All the other params are the same.

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();                    
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
if (method == "GET")
{
    stringBuilder.Append("GET&");
    stringBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(url));
    stringBuilder.Append("&");
    dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "oauth_version" , oauthVersion },
        { "oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey },
        { "oauth_nonce" , oauthNonce },
        { "oauth_signature_method" , oauthSignatureMethod },
        { "oauth_timestamp" , oauthTimeStamp },
        { "oauth_token" , accessToken },
    };
}

if (method == "POST")
{
    stringBuilder.AppendFormat("POST&{0}&", Uri.EscapeDataString(url));
    dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "oauth_version" , oauthVersion },
        { "oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey },
        { "oauth_nonce" , oauthNonce },
        { "oauth_signature_method" , oauthSignatureMethod },
        { "oauth_timestamp" , oauthTimeStamp },
        { "oauth_token" , accessToken },
        { "status" , status }
    };
}
```

Is there anyways to avoid duplicate in my code.Any suggestion would be handy.

Kindly regard.

Comment: What do you mean by _"duplicate"_? As far as a dictionary's keys there cannot be any duplicates. I find your question hard to understand, what _don't you want_ there to be a duplicate of?

Comment: @VisualVincent what I mean is if the method is POST I just need to add the status params.All the params in get and method are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't much see any relation between your `StringBuilder` instance variable and the dictionary that you are constructing, so assuming the duplication of the dictionary code, it can be taken out of those `if` conditions and then you could deal with the remaining `StringBuilder` instance like that:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}&{1}&", method, Uri.EscapeDataString(url));

var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
{
    { "oauth_version", oauthVersion },
    { "oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey },
    { "oauth_nonce", oauthNonce },
    { "oauth_signature_method", oauthSignatureMethod },
    { "oauth_timestamp", oauthTimeStamp },
    { "oauth_token", accessToken },
};

if (method == "POST")
{
    // Only add the status parameter if the method is POST
    dictionary["status"] = status;
}
```

So basically after this code executes both the `stringBuilder` and `dictionary` instance variables as shown in your question will have the expected values.

This being said, your dictionary looks like as if it contains query string parameter values. If this is the case then you more than definitely will want to properly url encode those values before ever consider sending them through the HTTP protocol:

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
{
    { "oauth_version", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthVersion) },
    { "oauth_consumer_key", Uri.EscapeDataString(consumerKey) },
    { "oauth_nonce", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthNonce) },
    { "oauth_signature_method", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignatureMethod) },
    { "oauth_timestamp", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthTimeStamp) },
    { "oauth_token", Uri.EscapeDataString(accessToken) },
};

if (method == "POST")
{
    // Only add the status parameter if the method is POST
    dictionary["status"] = Uri.EscapeDataString(status);
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin.What I meant is the post method just add this { "status" , status }  in to dictionary.Get method don't have { "status" , status }

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer with an example of how this can be achieved. You can just add the "status" parameter to the dictionary if the value of the method is POST.

Comment: Hi Darin,thanks for help.Why would I hadn't think about this